# C# X509Certificate2.PrivateKey threw exception "invalid provider type specified."

Tags: ssl-certificate, x509certificate2

I have a trusted CA issued SSL certificate installed on **Windows Server 2019**. When the following code in **ASP.NET MVC** controller was run, it did retrieve the **X509Certificate2**, its **HasProviateKey** property was **true**. But when its **PrivateKey** property was accessed, it threw a CryptographicException: "**invalid provider type specified.**"

```
    X509Certificate2 certificate = null;
    X509Store userCaStore = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
    userCaStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
    X509Certificate2Collection certificatesInStore = userCaStore.Certificates;
    X509Certificate2Collection findResult = certificatesInStore.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, "xyz...", true);

    if (findResult.Count != 1)
        throw new Exception("Certificate not found.");

    certificate = findResult[0];
    userCaStore.Close();
```

The reason I need to access the private key, was that the server needs to accept some long-lasting TCP socket connections, and I plan to use the SSL certificate's public/private key to do the typical handshake: the client generates a random AES key, and uses the public key to encrypt this AES key and sends it to the server. That is why I need to access the private key on the server side to decrypt the AES key.

How do I do it?

Comment: You should use `cert.GetRSAPrivateKey()` instead of `cert.PrivateKey`, and that should overcome your issue.

Comment: Thanks. I tried. cert.GetRSAPrivateKey() gets back a RSACng, but cert.PublicKey.Key gets back a RSACryptoServiceProvider. I tried to encrypt using the RSACryptoServiceProvider and decrypt using the RSACng, but it doesn't work. Please advise. Thanks.

Comment: I tried this code, and it throws exception "Key not valid for use in specified state.":  RSACng rsa = (RSACng)certificate.GetRSAPrivateKey();            rsa.Key.SetProperty(new CngProperty("Export Policy", itConverter.GetBytes((int)CngExportPolicies.AllowPlaintextExport), ngPropertyOptions.Persist));

Comment: Not sure why you’re messing with export policies if you just want to decrypt… just GetRSAPrivateKey and call Decrypt on that instance.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If you provide your answer then I can mark it as a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, partly. It has to do with the type of cryptography of the SSL certificate. I tried the same code to retrieve another trusted CA issued certificate and the **PrivateKey** property did present itself as RsaCryptoServiceProvider. The other thing that must be done is to right-click the certificate in the certificate store (mmc.exe) and select "All tasks | Manage private keys", and make sure the identity used by your code is there in a ACL.